# phpmyadmin import csv with difficult on date format

Tags: csv, import, phpmyadmin

i have a csv file with one of the column as format: 20131231  (eg. 2013-12-31)
i've a mysql table with field column 'date' with format int(10).
i want to use phpmyadmin to import the csv file so that the mysql table can accurately capture the date. Pls advise how to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create a temporary column to hold the date string, then import the csv as it is, then use the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE tablename SET actual_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(temp_date_column, '%Y/%m/%d');
```

[More info on STR_TO_DATE()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks. i use UPDATE tablename SET actual_col = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(temp_col);